# Javascript: submit button is not active when enter data to the form

Tags: javascript, html

I've picked up this code and it does not seem to work. The problem is the 'submit' button is not active when i try to click after i entered all the data to the form. Any help on where i am lacking? please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<form id="ourForm">
    <label>First Name</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function addEvent(to, type, fn){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        to.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if(document.attachEvent){
        to.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
    } else {
        to['on'+type] = fn;
    }  
};

 var Form = {

    validClass : 'valid',

    fname : {
        minLength : 1,     
        maxLength : 15,
        fieldName : 'First Name'
    },

    lname : {
        minLength : 1,     
        maxLength : 25,
        fieldName : 'Last Name'
    },

    validateLength : function(formEl, type){
        if(formEl.value.length > type.maxLength || formEl.value.length < type.minLength ){   
            formEl.className = formEl.className.replace(' '+Form.validClass, '');
            return false;
        } else {
            if(formEl.className.indexOf(' '+Form.validClass) == -1)
            formEl.className += ' '+Form.validClass;
            return true;
        }
    },

    validateEmail : function(formEl){
        var regEx = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
        var emailTest = regEx.test(formEl.value);       
        if (emailTest) {
            if(formEl.className.indexOf(' '+Form.validClass) == -1)        
            formEl.className += ' '+Form.validClass;           
            return true;
        } else {
            formEl.className = formEl.className.replace(' '+Form.validClass, '');
            return false;
        }          
    },     

    getSubmit : function(formID){   
        var inputs = document.getElementById(formID).getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            if(inputs[i].type == 'submit'){
                return inputs[i];
            }      
        }      
        return false;
    }          

}; 

addEvent(window, 'load', function(){

    var ourForm = document.getElementById('ourForm');  
    var submit_button = Form.getSubmit('ourForm');
    submit_button.disabled = 'disabled';

    function checkForm(){
        var inputs = ourForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if(Form.validateLength(inputs[0], Form.fname)){
            if(Form.validateLength(inputs[1], Form.lname)){
                if(Form.validateEmail(inputs[2])){                  

                        submit_button.disabled = false;
                        return true;

                }
            }
        }
        submit_button.disabled = 'disabled';
        return false;
    };

    checkForm();       
    addEvent(ourForm, 'keyup', checkForm);
    addEvent(ourForm, 'submit', checkForm);

});

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this in any particular browser? I pasted your code without any change and it seems to work for me: http://jsbin.com/jiqazebuce/1/

Comment: Also make sure you are entering a correct email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the code and tried the same code. It works. It might be that you filled all the three inputs but you did not put correct EMAIL that fulfills the EMAIL format(regex) in the code.
For example try to fill inputs with these three inputs someone, someone, someone@gmail.com; Submit is enabled